# grep serial numbers not starting with specific prefix

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have this file (serials.txt) containing serial numbers:

```
S/N:175-1915011190
S/N:244-1920023447
S/N:335-1920101144
S/N:244-1920101149
```

Using `grep` or similar tool I want to select all serials NOT starting with '244'
I'm able to select all the '244' with `grep -Eo '244-[0-9]*' serials.txt` but I want the opposite.
Something like `grep -Eo '(^244)-[0-9]*' serials.txt`

The output should be (without S/N:)

```
175-1915011190
335-1920101144
```

Comment: Use `grep -v ':244-' file`

Comment: Why not `tr -d 'S/N:' '' file | grep -v '244-'` ?

Comment: @t0mm13b That doesn't do what you expect, or you are being reckless.

Comment: @tripleee mea culpa, brain fart there on that.. `cat serials.txt | tr -d 'S/N:' | grep -v '244-'`

Comment: This still looks like you might not realize that this will delete all occurrences of `/`, `:`, `N`, and `S`. If the OP's data only contains numbers and dashes then fine; but `tr -dc '-0-9' <serials.txt` might seem more disciplined if that's what you actually mean. (Also notice how to avoid the useless `cat`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '!/S\/N:244/'   Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Above code will give complete line as output if you need starting from serial number to till end in output then following may help you.

```
awk -F':' '!/S\/N:244/{print $2}'   Input_file
```

***EDIT2:*** Adding a `sed` solution too here for same.

```
sed -n '/:244/d;s/.*://;p'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-v` option on grep would be helpful here, and then `cut` to remove the leading cruft:

```
grep -v ':244-' serials.txt | cut -c5-
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, without S/N:

```
grep -v ':244' serials.txt | cut -d':' -f2
```

Antigrep for :244, cuts with delimiter : shows field 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F':' '$2!~/^244/{print $2}' file
```